# Вопрос о приведении типов

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть абстрактный класс `Employee` со статическим `ArrayList<Employee> employeeList`. Также Есть 2 классы расширяющих `Employee`-- `EmployeeWithHourlyRate` и `EmployeeWithFixedPayment`. То есть, в `employeeList` будут записываться объекты двоих дочерних классов.

Как сделать, чтобы при взятии объектов из `employeeList` они приводились к своему типу (если мы положили `EmployeeWithFixedPayment`, то должны  забрать `EmployeeWithFixedPayment`, а не просто `Employee`)?

Объекты записываются в `employeeList` рандомно.

Comment: а что вам мешает хранить их в разных ArrayList ?

Comment: @alexander barakin потом будет нужно сортировать всех сотрудников по ЗП

Comment: ну для отчета вы можете сливать их в одну коллекцию, а работать с двумя разными. Впрочем не важно, я вам написал ответ, вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: @Dmitry V. да, спасибо. То есть, правильнее будет сделать для каждого класса свой ArrayList, но сортировать по ЗП, добавляя двa ArrayList   через addAll() в коллекцию employeeList и уже там делать сортировку ?

Comment: зависит от ситуации. с двумя типами можно и так обойтись, но будет еще пара - запутаетесь в кастах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вообще вы можете приводить их вручную при помощи instanceof:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TOP> list = ImmutableList.of(new L(), new R(), new L());

        list.forEach(x -> {
            if (x instanceof L) {
                L l = (L) x;
            } else {
                R r = (R) x;
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TOP {

    }

    public static class L  extends  TOP { }
    public static class R  extends  TOP { }

}
```